# Visual Studio 2012 creates .delete file extension during debug

Tags: asp.net

This is a hard question to google because all the result want to teach me about deleting files with .net code. My issue is that when I start debugging on my website, I get an error saying some dll library cannot be found. What I have discovered by my own digging into the Windows folders is that the missing dll library exists, but the file name has been appended with a random character string and then .delete.

> Compiler Error Message: BC2017: could not find library
>   'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\2e10144d\af715c24\App_Web_wvrswv50.dll'

[image: App_Web_wvrswv50.dll.2fd162c1.delete]

If I change the file name, removing the random characters and .delete file extension, then restart the debugger in Visual Studio, the website will load fine for an indeterminate number of debug sessions.

Comment: When you google on something like this, try quoting the ".delete" so it knows to seek that whole string.  [my search brought me this](https://shazwazza.com/post/taming-the-buildmanager-aspnet-temp-files-and-appdomain-restarts/)

Comment: Also if you're seeing it here, you may have to find the source DLL and readd it to your project, I'm not 100% on the integrity of these temporary files.

Comment: [Refresh Assemblies section](http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/under-hood)